# How to emit from vue render

Tags: vue.js, emit

I am rendering a component using `render()` and not from an HTML template. I would like to emit a property from the component I am rendering, but I am not sure how to get that in a rendered component (I would use `@` in an HTML template).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In vue 3 it seems to be a bit different when using syntactic sugar.

In the child:

```js
const emits = defineEmits(['delete']);

then

<button @click="emits('delete')">delete</button>
```

```js
   render(h(bar, {
      onDelete: (ev) => {
        console.log(ev)
      }
```

Notice the `on` should be added to the `onDelete`

Comment: indeed, it works. Where have you spot this in the doc or in the code ?

Comment: @Daividh Was just a lucky take when i had to use it. seems to be documented now though. https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#h

Answer (score 1):

The VNode data [object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) handles events through the `on` property:

```js
on: {
  click: this.clickHandler
}
```

Assuming you are rendering a `<child>` component which emits a `myevent` event, you would render it and handle the event as follows:

```js
render(h) {
  return h('child', {
    on: {
      myevent: this.onMyevent
    }
  });
}
```

Where `onMyevent` is just a normal handler method:

```js
methods: {
  onMyevent(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note this answer is for Vue 2, as was the question.